# Expectation Maximization - question about the 2 different formulations of E-Step

Tags: statistics, conditional-expectation, machine-learning

I saw the following 2 formulations for the E-Step:

$Q(θ,θ_t )=E_{θ_t} ( log(p_θ (X,Z))│X=x)$

$Q(θ,θ_t )= E_{Z|X,θ_t } [log(Pr_θ(X=x,Z))]$

I can't understand why they are equal.

Comment: the algorithm is explained here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expectation%E2%80%93maximization_algorithm#Proof_of_correctness and where does your first formula come from ?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AnbiNaVp3eQ
You can see it on 8:35

Comment: I don't know what means for him the 1st formula, while by definition if $Z$ takes only discrete values : $$\mathbb{E}_{Z | X,\theta_t} [f(Z)] = \sum_{z} p(Z=z|X,\theta_t) f(z)$$ and because by definition $Q(\theta,\theta_t) = \mathbb{E}_{Z | X,\theta_t} [g(Z)]$ with $g(Z) = \log p(X=x,Z|\theta)$ we get
$$Q(\theta,\theta_t) = \sum_{z} p(Z=z|X,\theta_t) \log P(X=x,Z=z|\theta)$$
all the problem being the prove that applying the EM algorithm to $Q(\theta,\theta_t)$ is equivalent to maximize the likelihood $L(X;\theta)$

Comment: Great I think I got it, so g(Z) is the log likelihood for the joint distribution of X and Z? $g(Z)=log(L(\theta;(X,Z)))$

Comment: $g(z)$ is the function $\log L(\theta; (X,Z))$ taken at the point $(X=x,Z=z)$ (so $g$ is what you said but with $X=x$ fixed !! it depends only on $z$)

Comment: and read again https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expectation%E2%80%93maximization_algorithm#Proof_of_correctness to be sure you understood why each EM step on $Q(\theta,\theta_t)$ increases $L(\theta;X)$

Comment: Isn't the input for g a random variable(Z)? and not a point (z). Anyway, by what you are saying(that X is fixed in g) then I think that it is not the log likelihood for the joint distribution of X and Z..:|